# Firestore storage Angular2 Update Profile Image for a mobile app

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have an IONIC-Angular mobile app in which a user will be able to update their profile and one of the features is giving the user the ability to change their profile image. I have been searching around but cannot find good examples how to achieve this.

I would like to have the user go to the 'Profile Detail Page', click on a button to update Profile Image, have the mobile app open the gallery to select an image from, after selecting image, storing the image in Google Firestore Storage, and a reference to this image in a document on Firestore to be able to reference the image to display it. Is there any tutorial or an example of how to do this as I have been battling to find a simple example

Comment: Maybe you can find the following [link](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=1052) useful?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know that you can find that specific example but a great example on using firebase storage is:

[Upload Multiple Files to Firebase Storage with Angular](https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-firebase-storage-uploads-multi/)